# Css hover triggering on a completely random element

Tags: html, css

I am making a nested html menu. And for some reason, the hover keeps triggering way before you actually hover on the correct element. It's as if another div or element is triggering it before hand.

I think it has to do with my HTML structure and the way I am calling the hover in css.

See snippets below -

```css
/*CAR ASSISTANT STYLES*/

.car-assist-container {
 position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}

.assist-label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.assist-label:hover > .assist-list {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.assist-list {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #141825;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: block;
}

.assist-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d2435;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    transition: ocolor 0.4s ease;
}

.assist-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}

.browse:after {
 content: '▸';
}

.browse:hover > .browse-list{
 opacity: 1;
}

.browse-list{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #1d2435;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}

.browse-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #141825;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.browse-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-assist-container">
  <a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant
              <ul class="assist-list">
                <li class="assist-item" id="carWorth">Car Worth</li>
                <li class="assist-item browse">
                  Browse
                  <ul class="browse-list">
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseMake">Makes</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseType">Types</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseYear">Year</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="assist-item">Compare</li>
              </ul>
          </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected behaviour

Comment: Well the hover is triggering as you hover to the right of it. It should just triggering when hovering in the a link and then the browse list item

Comment: You're using opacity:0 to hide your sub-menu which is catching the hover event, because it's there, just transparent.

Comment: You need to animate something other than `opacity`. Try `visibility` or `height`.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably your desired behaviour, with minimal code change.

```css
/*CAR ASSISTANT STYLES*/

.car-assist-container {
 position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}

.assist-label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.assist-label:hover > .assist-list {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.assist-list {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #141825;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: block;

overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
}

.assist-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d2435;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    transition: ocolor 0.4s ease;
}

.assist-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}

.browse:after {
 content: '▸';
}

.browse:hover > .browse-list{
 opacity: 1;
    height: auto;

}

.browse-list{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #1d2435;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.browse-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #141825;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.browse-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-assist-container">
  <a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant
              <ul class="assist-list">
                <li class="assist-item" id="carWorth">Car Worth</li>
                <li class="assist-item browse">
                  Browse
                  <ul class="browse-list">
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseMake">Makes</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseType">Types</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseYear">Year</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="assist-item">Compare</li>
              </ul>
          </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `.browse-list` div is on the top of your `.assist-label`, so when you hover over the `.assist-label`, your are actually hovering over `.browse-list`.

Answer (score 0):

You're animating the opacity, I've changed it from display: block; to display: none; and we're switching those values now on hover. Seems to trigger at the right moment now. However you're submenu is still not working correctly but I did not look into that as that was not the question ;-)

```css
/*CAR ASSISTANT STYLES*/

.car-assist-container {
 position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 210px;
}

.assist-label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    float: left;
    padding: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.assist-label:hover > .assist-list {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
display:block;
}

.assist-list {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #141825;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  display: none;
}

.assist-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1d2435;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: color 0.4s ease;
    transition: ocolor 0.4s ease;
}

.assist-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}

.browse:after {
 content: '▸';
}

.browse:hover > .browse-list{
 opacity: 1;
    display:block;
}

.browse-list{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #1d2435;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    display:none;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}

.browse-item{
    color: white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #141825;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.browse-item:hover {
 color: #d40000;
}
```

```html
<div class="car-assist-container">
  <a href="#" class="assist-label" id="label">Car Assistant
              <ul class="assist-list">
                <li class="assist-item" id="carWorth">Car Worth</li>
                <li class="assist-item browse">
                  Browse
                  <ul class="browse-list">
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseMake">Makes</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseType">Types</li>
                    <li class="browse-item" id="browseYear">Year</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="assist-item">Compare</li>
              </ul>
          </a>
</div>
```